# I want to add space between numeric and alphanumeric characters

Tags: c#

When the textbox changes I want add a whitespace between numeric and alphanumeric characters.

For example

```
34 YT 567 *Allowed*
22 KL 2345 *Allowed*
22KL 2345 *Not Allowed*
22KL2345 *Not Allowed*
22 KL2345 *Not Allowed*
```

Comment: Personally I'd do this when validating, not after every change.  For example, as a user, if I position the cursor in front of the "K" and press backspace three times, I'd expect the "22 " to be deleted - if you add the space after each change, it will have no effect.

Comment: @mcalex, that's his question. If someone adds without space he needs to add a space.

Comment: `var newtext = String.Join(" ", Regex.Matches("34YT567", @"\d+|[A-Z]+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value));`

Comment: @Kaf yah, question got edited.

Answer (score 3):

This will fix an incorrect value by inserting spaces where necessary:

```
var correctedValue = Regex.Replace(
    incorrectValue,
    "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])",
    " ");
```

You can use the same pattern to detect an incorrect value using `Regex.IsMatch` if you want to warn the user rather than fix it automatically.

Edit:

```
Regex.IsMatch(MyTextBox.Text,
    "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]")
```

will return `true` if the user inputs a number next to a letter, or inputs any non-alphanumeric (and non-space) character.

If you want to *remove* non-alphanumeric characters and *insert* spaces you'll need to do it in two steps; first `Regex.Replace` with pattern `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]`, then the `Regex.Replace` call above.

Comment: This answer is good but i want to use just numeric and alphanumeric character in textbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find bad input using RegEx.

```
Regex rgx = new RegEx("([0-9]+[a-z]|[A-Z]+)||([a-z]|[A-Z]+[0-9]+)");
if (rgx.IsMatch(MyTextBox.Text)
{
     //bad input
}
else
    //input was good.
```

The regular expression is matching one or more numbers followed directly by one or more letters or the other way around (letters then numbers).

Comment: This answer is good but I want use just numeric and upper alphanumeric characters in textbox. Thanks

Comment: @BülentAlaçam That's not the question you asked.